# Symfony - activate user by sending mail with HASH URL

Tags: php, symfony, email, url, hash

Is there a built-in method or library in Symfony 2.7 to activate accounts by hashed url in mail?
It's a process of registration:
-enter data
-create user with column "authenticated = false"
- **send mail with url (for example http://url.com/activate/H@$H) 
-authenticate by this hash (how?)**

The other option is just to make a column called account_hash, find an accout by account_hash and set activated to true but i'm pretty sure there is the easiest option buit in symfony

Comment: Take a look to FOS User Bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle